# Get custom block type image field in Display Suite twig field

Tags: 8

I have a custom block type with a link field and an image field. I want to combine those fields to wrap the image in the link.

I created a Display Suite Twig field. What do I use to show the image?

Ideally the image as rendered in *Manage display*, but as long as I can show the image with a certain image style, I'd be very happy.

This is what I have already tried.

```
{{ file_url(node.field_career_highlight_image.entity.uri.value) }}
{{ file_url(content.field_career_highlight_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
{{ file_url(block_content.field_career_highlight_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}
{{ file_url(node.field_career_highlight_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
{{ block_content.field_career_highlight_image.alt }} - shows alt, just experimenting, so wondering why this didn't work for the image
{{ content.field_career_highlight_image }}
{{ block_content.field_career_highlight_image }} - white screen
{{ block_content.field_career_highlight_image.0 }}
{{ block_content.field_career_highlight_image.0.value }}
{{ block_content.field_career_highlight_image[0] }}
{{ block_content['#block_content'].field_career_highlight_image.value }}
{{ content['#block_content'].field_career_highlight_image.value }}
{{ content['#block_content'].field_career_highlight_image }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% set image_uri = block_content.field_feature_row_image['#items'].entity.uri.value %}

<img src="{{ image_uri|image_style('thumbnail') }}"/>
```

OR with a .0

```
{% set image_uri = block_content.field_feature_row_image.0['#items'].entity.uri.value %}

<img src="{{ image_uri|image_style('thumbnail') }}"/>
```

---

If not, try

```
{{ file_url(block_content.field_career_highlight_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

---

If still no dice, then give this a shot. In /sites/default/**settings.php** add:

```
// Override default twig method whitelist.
$settings['twig_sandbox_whitelisted_methods'] = [
  // Defaults:
  'id',
  'label',
  'bundle',
  'get',
  '__toString',
  'toString',
  // Additions:
  'url',
];
```

and then in your field twig put

```
{{ block_content.field_career_highlight_image.url }}
```

Comment: This one worked: {{ file_url(block_content.field_career_highlight_image.entity.fileuri) }}. It got the original file uploaded and I understand why. Unfortunately, the nature of the platform doesn't give me access to settings.php, which is a bummer. My ultimate goal is to be able to access the version of a certain image style, but I wasn't able to figure that with your solutions. I'm going to mark your answer as accepted because you did answer my core question.